# Map reference starting point shifted

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, extents

I am loading an nc4 raster downloaded from a public dataset to QGIS and it first displays an error that the data does not have CRS. Then, it charges the map but the reference point 0 is shifted the map starts in Europe (I see most of the maps start in America on right side). Therefore, when I add an openstreet map layer, both maps don't match. I have tried changing the CRS but when I do that the map appears cropped. 
I attach an image of the problem [image]